# Date returned from OPENQUERY is converted to DATETIME when I fetch the data in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am querying IBM DB2 Linked server to fetch data to my MS Management Studion 2012, since I have limited access to the tables on the linked server I use premade queries so when I execute my open query :

```
  select TOP 100 *
    from openquery(LinkedServer,
    '
    select 
    someTable.Date AS BIRTHDATE,
    ...
```

in the `Result Window` of Management studio I get

```
BIRTHDATE
1969-08-31
```

which is exactly how I want to show it to the use. However I'm fetching the data using `ADO.NET` :

```
while (reader.Read())
  {
    for (int k = 0; k < columns.Count; k++)
    {
      resultRow.Add(reader[k]);
    }
  }
 reader.Close();
```

and for some reason instead of getting the well formatted `1969-08-31` I get `1969-08-31T00:00:00`.

I tried adding this code:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), someTable.Date, 23) AS BIRTHDAY
```

but I got error - `SQL0204 - CONVERT in *LIBL type *N not found.`. Since it's nto the first time that I have problems using `SQL SERVER` functions on `DB2` server I think that maybe I just can't use this function. However in the `Ms Management Studio` I get the correct format and since I want to keep thing somewhat dynamic I don't want to aplly the format later when I fetch the recrods with `ADO.NET` so I wonder if there's any way to keep this format and prevent `ADO.NET` from adding this `T00:00:00`

Comment: It would probably work with `select TOP 100 ..., CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), BIRTHDAY, 23) AS BIRTHDAY from openquery(LinkedServer,` i.e. use the function on SQL Server's side. Although really, if you get back a `System.DateTime` you should be aware that dates and times don't have an inherit string representation. Call `ToString` and specify the format you want.

Comment: Yeah, it works but I have to move out all columns I want which is not what I ultimately want to end up with.

Answer (score 1):

please use convert(varchar(10),someTable.Date,120) function like:

```
convert(varchar(10),someTable.Date,120)
```

And also refer: [click here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though keep in mind that link to w3shcools are not tolerated here. MSDN has this on their site, maybe change the link to point there.

Comment: It's not working, but +1 for the effort and the well formatted answer!